# Getting reference from model One2many relationship comodel inside an ir.actions.act_window

Tags: odoo

Would like to ask on how you can get the id of the comodel inside the `ir.actions.act_window`.

See my source code: https://gist.github.com/renesansz/2642b02875475383605e

Currently, I cannot get the `sprint_id.project_id.current_sprint` reference since it's giving me an error of `Uncaught Error: NameError: name 'sprint_id' is not defined`. So what I wanted to happen is that upon opening the project it should add a default filter for the current sprint of the project.

Do I have any alternative for this kind of approach?

Tried doing domain, but still no luck solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: make related field and then use this field in xml view.

Comment: related='sprint_id.project_id.current_sprint'